# Oauth2 server example with all 4 grant types

Tags: authentication, spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0

Is it possible to have an auth server defining all four types of grant types?
And if yes then how can I test them? A sample auth client for grant type password would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I am presuming that you want to implement it using Spring OAuth server implementation. One example by Dave Syer is hosted on [GitHub](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/blob/master/tests/annotation/jdbc/src/main/java/demo/Application.java), and it uses JDBC as the token store.

Now for the grant types, you have the option to configure that per client that you register with your OAuth server. You will notice that it has been setup using "authorizedGrantTypes" in the example below.

For testing - password grant type is very easy to test using a REST client like Postman and making a call to the OAuth server.

Feel free to comment on this if you need more help. All the best!

**Resource Server**

```
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
protected static class ResourceServer extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private TokenStore tokenStore;

    @Override
    public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources)
            throws Exception {
        resources.tokenStore(tokenStore);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated();
    }

}
```

**Authorization Server**

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
protected static class OAuth2Config extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager auth;

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    private BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();

    @Bean
    public JdbcTokenStore tokenStore() {
        return new JdbcTokenStore(dataSource);
    }

    @Bean
    protected AuthorizationCodeServices authorizationCodeServices() {
        return new JdbcAuthorizationCodeServices(dataSource);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer security)
            throws Exception {
        security.passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints)
            throws Exception {
        endpoints.authorizationCodeServices(authorizationCodeServices())
                .authenticationManager(auth).tokenStore(tokenStore())
                .approvalStoreDisabled();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
        // @formatter:off
        clients.jdbc(dataSource)
                .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder)
            .withClient("my-trusted-client")
                .authorizedGrantTypes("password", "authorization_code",
                        "refresh_token", "implicit")
                .authorities("ROLE_CLIENT", "ROLE_TRUSTED_CLIENT")
                .scopes("read", "write", "trust")
                .resourceIds("oauth2-resource")
                .accessTokenValiditySeconds(60).and()
            .withClient("my-client-with-registered-redirect")
                .authorizedGrantTypes("authorization_code")
                .authorities("ROLE_CLIENT").scopes("read", "trust")
                .resourceIds("oauth2-resource")
                .redirectUris("http://anywhere?key=value").and()
            .withClient("my-client-with-secret")
                .authorizedGrantTypes("client_credentials", "password")
                .authorities("ROLE_CLIENT").scopes("read")
                .resourceIds("oauth2-resource").secret("secret");
        // @formatter:on
    }

}
```